# I would like some advice on how to implement a SharePoint call logging system

Tags: sharepoint, logging

Is it possible to build a call logging system within SharePoint?
We would also need ot interate reporting, filtering, some basic forms functionality, etc.

Comment: On what level would you like to intercept? Pretty much everything in SharePoint is already logged in the ULS. For reporting there are Reporting Services for SharePoint and when it comes to forms at least I don't understand.

Comment: I mean call logging as in an application such as someone called me, I need to record the time, add what the phonecall was about, add a document, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you should create is a custom list and fill with columns that suits your needs. There are many tutorials on this and you are probably best of at youtube.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmVy5roiKzg
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P84as3ZNoeM

Comment: if I want to integrate data with the list then this would require custom development? Is this a good use for SharePoint or should this type of thing be bespoke software?

Comment: There are many API's to SharePoint and depending on your skills and needs there are different. The most widely spread 3rd party api is Camelot .NET Connector for SharePoint that makes SharePoint lists look like a SQL Server. http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/